# MATLAB convertion from grayscale(INTESITY) to truecolor(RGB)

Tags: matlab, colors

I know how to do the opposite `rgb2gray(img)` but I **can't** find a function `gray2rgb(img)` that can convert from *grayscale* to *truecolor*.

Is there another function that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nice function made by Gabriel Frangakis](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28111-gray2rgb/content/gray2rgb.m):

```
function [Image]=gray2rgb(Image)
%Gives a grayscale image an extra dimension
%in order to use color within it
[m n]=size(Image);
rgb=zeros(m,n,3);
rgb(:,:,1)=Image;
rgb(:,:,2)=rgb(:,:,1);
rgb(:,:,3)=rgb(:,:,1);
Image=rgb/255;
end
```

you should make the gray value for each coordinate `RGB`

Comment: Can I 'duplicate' the image using cat: cat(3, img, img, img) ?